# Removing cookie with Codeception

Tags: php, cookies, acceptance-testing, codeception

I just started using Codeception to write acceptance tests for my login application in PHP. What I need to do is to remove a cookie that has been set and I've been using resetCookie() to do that but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
$I = new WebGuy($scenario);
$I->wantTo('ensure that login page is correct');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->click("Log in");
$I->see("cookie");
$I->resetCookie("test");
$I->reloadPage();
$I->dontSee("cookie");
```

So basically I set a cookie in my application when the Log in button is clicked and if that cookie is present I echo a string on the site that says "cookie". In the browser when the cookie is removed and the page is reloaded the "cookie" string disappears. This is what the test is trying to mimic.

For some reason, resetCookie() doesn't do anything because the test fails at the last step. Am I using it wrong or is there another way to do it? I would really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: I don't understand this test or why it works. $I->see looks for WORDS ON THE RENDERED PAGE, not cookies! You're not dontSee it later.

Comment: I believe he has a script that will display the word 'cookie' if the cookie is set, if not, the text is not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test works 100%.

Also try:

```
$I->setCookie('test','cookie text');
$I->seeCookie('test');
$I->resetCookie('test');
$I->seeCookie('test');
```

If the above test passes, then something else might be blocking you from setting a cookie on the page you are testing.

I tested using Webdriver.
Here's my config file.

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver
        - WebHelper

    config:

        WebDriver:
          url: http://www.example.com 
          host: localhost 
          port: 4444
          browser: firefox 
          delay: 1000
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly with WebDriver. PhpBrowser still doesn't work but I can live with that.